# Evento mouseover y mouseout en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy haciendo una pequeña pagina de prueba en html,js,css y tengo unas fotos que al pasar el mouse quiero que se agregue el botón para borrar cada imagen y cuando no este sobre la imagen desaparezca, logre hacer el evento claro con mouseover y mouseout el problema es que cuando paso sobre la imagen y aparece el botón para borrarla se desacomoda la imagen respecto a las otras. Como logro hacer que no se muevan y que solo aparezca el botón.

```js
function crearAlbum(imge, nomb, ide) {
  id++;
  var divColumnas = document.createElement('div');
  divColumnas.className = "columnas";
  var divContenido = document.createElement('div');
  divContenido.className = "contenido";
  divContenido.id = ide;
  var divBotton = document.createElement('div');
  divBotton.className = 'divBorrar';

  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = imge;
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = nomb;
  var buttonBorrar = document.createElement('button');
  buttonBorrar.className = 'buttonBorrar';
  buttonBorrar.textContent = "X";
  buttonBorrar.id = id;
  buttonBorrar.addEventListener('click', borrarFoto);
  buttonBorrar.style.display = 'none';


  divContenido.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    buttonBorrar.style.display = 'block';
  });
  divContenido.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    buttonBorrar.style.display = 'none';
  });

  divBotton.appendChild(buttonBorrar);
  divContenido.appendChild(img);
  divContenido.appendChild(p);
  divColumnas.appendChild(divContenido);
  divColumnas.appendChild(divBotton);
  contenedorFotos.appendChild(divColumnas);

  $('.contenido').click(function() {

    console.log("vistaAlbums");

    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    console.log(id);

    window.open("albums.html?" + models + id, "_self", true);
  });
}
//Mostrar texto de imagen cargada
$('#file_1').on('change', function() {
  $('#inputval').text($(this).val());
});

var fileButton = document.getElementById('file_1');

fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

  //Obtener archivo
  file = e.target.files[0];



});




//function cerrarFormulario() {
var cerrar = $('#cerrar').click(function() {

  var fade = document.getElementById('fade');
  fade.style.display = 'none';


});
//} //cerrarFormulario
```

```css
.divBorrar {
  .buttonBorrar {
    width: 13px;
    height: 15px;
    position: relative;
    left: 198px;
    bottom: 259px;
    font-size: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

Comment: falta el html y css para que tu codigo sea funcional

Comment: El css lo agregue abajo y el html lo estoy agregando todo desde js

Comment: al final no pusiste el html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mas probable es que tu problema sea de css. Mi recomendación es que pruebes a hacer lo siguiente:
Hacé que aparezcan todos los botones sobre las imagenes sin el evento. Acomodá las cosas con HTML y CSS para que aparezcan encima (probá con z-index, float o display inline, hay varias formas de poner cosas una arriba de la otra).
Y una vez que aparezcan gráficamente como vos querés, recién ahí le metés el evento mouseover, y probás.

Comment: Gracias por responder, al parecer estaba agregando mal el boton ya que debía agregarlo dentro del mismo div en lugar de agregar un solo div para el boton pero la propiedad z-index me ayudo.

Answer (score 1):

Si intentas usar la propiedad visible o hidden para cada foto.

Ejemplo:

```
<div id="contenedor principal">


<div id="foto1" on mouseover="funcionMostrarBoton(1)" onmouseout="funcionOcultarBoton(1)" >
<div id="botonFoto1"></div>

</div>

<div id="foto1" on mouseover="funcionMostrarBoton(2)" onmouseout="funcionOcultarBoton(2)" >
<div id="botonFoto2"></div>
</div>

<div id="foto1" on mouseover="funcionMostrarBoton(3)" onmouseout="funcionOcultarBoton(3)" >
<div id="botonFoto3"></div>
</div>

</div>


function funcionMostrarBoton(varIdBoton){
document.getElementById('botonFoto'+varIdBoton).style.visibility='visible';
}

function funcionOcultarBoton(varIdBoton){
document.getElementById('botonFoto'+varIdBoton).style.visibility='hidden';
}
```

Me cuentas que tal te fue